# Is there a connection between stopOver and numberOfStops?

Tags: tickets, bookings, gds

When communicating programmatically with the Sabre GDS, in the documentation I always find the fields stopOver and numberOfStops. I always assumed they are related, but today someone argued that they represent different things, but I couldn't understand the difference.

Could someone explain it?

For reference, a GDS (Global Distribution System) basically manages the distribution of travel-related products, historically the flights. Interaction with a GDS is usually about getting availabilities, details or booking a flight.

Comment: Which API is this?

Comment: For those of us who don't know, what is a GDS?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really about travel, it's about programming and communicating with a specific API. Probably should be moved to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Calchas: the current development is related to Sabre, but Amadeus & Galileo has something similar

Comment: The service provide should provide you with this documentation.  While they are likely different (because conceptually, they are), an API is always defined at the discretion of the owner.

Comment: @Johns-305: how are they conceptually different? Their docs generally only say something like "NBRSTP: Number Of Stops". It doesn't explain anything else. In the examples I've found the numberOfStop field is 0 or 1, but the docs say Its a numeric field (so I' should assume 999 is a valid value for this field?). What does this field actually mean?

Comment: @Quamis "Travel experts" would have no idea how to answer— this site is for people who use the tools, not build them. The vendor, as others have noted, is the only one who can provide a definitive answer.

Comment: @choster: I've send a question to Sabre, but the typical answer time is about 1 month, and I need to make a development that would reach the client tomorrow... I was hoping that someone else encountered these terms before and could explain them from the user-perspective(so the people who use the tools are my target here). Johns-305 mentioned that they are conceptually different, but I'm not seeing any difference between the 2 terms.

Comment: @Quamis Because an Itinerary can have, say, 2 stops, with one being a Stopover, as opposed to a Connection.  But again, who ever developed this particular API may have interpreted stopOver differently.  I can think of at least one case where this would be sort of legit.

Comment: What values does stopOver have?

Comment: @phoog: O or X ...

Comment: Typically, a _Stopover_ is a voluntary interruption of the flight leg sequence, where the customer walks out of the airport to do whatever, normally between 1 and 364 days. A _Stop_ is a change of flights, either the plane or the Flight #, or even just a interruption, like a bus stopping at the bus stop. The first is typically by customer wish; the second is by necessity (of connections or associated prices). Now the API might use other definitions, who knows.

Comment: @Aganju: thx, it makes sense. i never thought of "necessity" for stops, and I thought those were present in the list of segments with stopOver=X. I was wrong